# Need to generate excel using vb script?

Tags: vba, vbscript, qtp

I am trying to run test cases using driver script, which i had developed in vb script.(below is some part of code that launches QTP), and lanuched qtp script generate XLS reports. now issue is that when i invoke test suite using vb driver script, it creates files which include result rows as well blank rows (upto 65635).  this problem leads to result file(.XLS) sixed in MBs which should not include blank rows and must be in KBs.i also checked running test cases using QTP directly but i did not face any issues and size were in KB.

```
            Dim qtApp, Test_Path
            Dim BasePath
            Dim qtTest
            BasePath = "some path"
            Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
            qtApp.Launch
            qtApp.Visible = True
            Test_Path = BasePath & "\" & scriptname
            qtApp.Open Test_Path, True              
            Set qtTest = qtApp.Test
            qtTest.Run
                 qtTest.Close
            qtApp.Quit
            Set qtTest = Nothing
            Set qtApp = Nothing
```

kindly some one please let me know why the same script running using external VBs gives such huge result file?

Thanks in advance,

Priyank Shah

Answer (score 0):

Implement the temp sheet creation in run time and generate the excel sheets. Also make sure that you set nothing on each excel object you declared.

`Set objExcel = Nothing`